# Run multiple instances of Xcode instruments via command line

Tags: xcode, instruments

Is it possible to run multiple instances of instruments via command line. Currently Instruments hangs, when i try to run 2 instances of instruments simultaneously.

Comment: No but you can run multiple `iprofiler` instances...

Answer (score 1):

You can only have 1 instance of instruments running per Xcode. But, you can have multiple Xcode installs. You can also have multiple profiles running in a single instance of instruments.